# Normalization of the ring $\mathbb{C}[x^3,xy^2,y^3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that the ring $\mathbb{C}[x^3,xy^2,y^3]$ is not normal and give its normalization.

I don't know how find the normalization. Clearly, the field of fractions of the ring is integrally closed but I guess it's too big. Given that, I am considering exploring the minimal extension of the ring that is normal. However, I am currently unsure about how to proceed in this regard. So far, I've only found $x^2y$ as a non-trivial integral element. I don't how to find the rest if there is a method.

Note: The OP's question is not a duplicate of

$\qquad$ [Integral closure of $k[x^3,x^2y,y^3]$ in field of fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695644/integral-closure-of-kx3-x2y-y3-in-field-of-fractions)

since, despite the title, the question in the above link doesn't actually ask for the integral closure, nor does the answer in the above link address the problem of finding the integral closure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral closure of $k[x^3,x^2y,y^3]$ in field of fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695644/integral-closure-of-kx3-x2y-y3-in-field-of-fractions) (relabel $x \leftrightarrow y$; found via [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz))

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x^3,xy^2,y^3]$.

Our goal is to determine whether or not $R$ is integrally closed, and if not, to find the integral closure of $R$.

Let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$.

From the identity
$$
x^2y
=
\frac
{x^3y^3}{xy^2}
$$
it follows that $x^2y\in K$.

Let $F=\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Consider the ring $F[y^2,y^3]$ . . .

It's clear that $x^3,xy^2,y^3\in F[y^2,y^3]$, hence $R\subseteq F[y^2,y^3]$.

Note that we actually have $R\subset F[y^2,y^3]$ (proper inclusion) since, for example, $x^{-1}\in F$ but $x^{-1}\not\in R$.

Also we have
$$
F[y^2,y^3]
=
a_0
+
\sum_{n=2}^\infty
a_ny^n
$$
where at most finitely many of $a_2,a_3,a_4,...$ are nonzero.

From the above characterization of $F[y^2,y^3]$, it follows that $y\not\in F[y^2,y^3]$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
y\not\in F[y^2,y^3]
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x^2y\not\in F[y^2,y^3]
&&
\bigl(\,
\text{since $x^2\in F$}
\,\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x^2y\not\in R
&&
\bigl(\,
\text{since $R\subset F[y^2,y^3]$}
\,\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Also, from $x^3,y^3\in R$, we get $x^6y^3\in R$, hence from the identity
$$
(x^2y)^3=x^6y^3
$$
it follows that $x^2y$ is integral over $R$.

Thus we have
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
&x^2y\in K.\\[4pt]
&x^2y\not\in R.\\[4pt]
&\text{$x^2y$ is integral over $R$.}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
hence $R$ is not integrally closed.

Let $T=\mathbb{C}[x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3]$.

It's clear that $R\subset T$.

Since $K$ is the fraction field of $R$, and since $x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3\in K$, it follows that $K$ is also the fraction field of $T$.

Let $V\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be the set of all monomials $ax^iy^j$ with nonzero $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $i+j$ is a multiple of $3$.

We need some lemmas . . .

**Lemma $(1)$:**$\;V\subset T$

Let $f\in V$, say $f=ax^iy^j$.

By the division algorithm, we can write
\begin{align*}
i&=3q_1+r_1\\[4pt]
j&=3q_2+r_2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where $q_1,q_2,r_1,r_2$ are nonnegative integers with $r_1,r_2\le 2$.

Since $1\in T$ and $x^3,y^3\in T$, we get $x^{3q_1}y^{3q_2}\in T$.

Since $i+j$ is a multiple of $3$, it follows that $r_1+r_2$ is a multiple of $3$.

Then from $0\le r_1,r_2\le 2$, we get $(r_1,r_2)\in \bigl\{(0,0),(1,2),(2,1)\bigr\}$,
hence since $1,xy^2,x^2y\in T$, it follows that $x^{r_1}y^{r_2}\in T$.

Then we get
$$
f
=
ax^iy^j
=
ax^{3q_1+r_1}y^{3q_2+r_2}
=
a
\bigl(
x^{3q_1}y^{3q_2}
\bigr)
\bigl(
x^{r_1}y^{r_2}
\bigr)
\in
T
$$
which completes the proof of lemma $(1)$.

**Lemma $(2)$:**$\;$For $f\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, we have $\;f\in T$ if and only if every monomial of $f$ is an element of $V$.

It's clear that $V$ is closed under multiplication, hence the claim that every monomial of $f$ is an element of $V$ follows from the fact that the ring generators
$x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3$ of $T$ over $K$ are elements of $V$.

Conversely, if $f\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is such that every monomial of $f$ is an element of $V$, the claim that $f\in T$ follows from the fact that $V\subset T$.

This completes the proof of lemma $(2)$.

As an immediate corollary (trivial proof omitted), we have

**Corollary to lemma $(2)$:**$\;$For $f\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, we have $\;f\in T$ if and only if the degree of each nonzero homogeneous component of $f$ is a multiple of $3$.

In the next lemma, for nonzero $g\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, we'll use the notation $\ell(g)$ to denote the leading form (homogeneous component of highest degree) of $g$.

**Lemma $(3)$:**$\;\mathbb{C}[x,y]\cap K=T$.

The inclusion $T\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x,y]\cap K$ is immediate since $T\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $T\subset K$.

For the reverse inclusion, suppose $f\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]\cap K$.

If $f=0$, then $f\in T$.

Suppose $f\ne 0$.

Then since $f\in K$ and $K$ is the fraction field of $T$, we can write
$f={\large{\frac{p}{q}}}$ for some nonzero $p,q\in T$.

From $p=qf$, we get $\deg(\ell(p))=\deg(\ell(q))+\deg(\ell(f))$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
p,q\in T
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\ell(p),\ell(q)\in V
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3{\mid}\deg(\ell(p))
\;\text{and}\;
3{\mid}\deg(\ell(q))
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3{\mid}\deg(\ell(f))
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\ell(f)\in V
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\ell(f)\in T
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Let $m$ be the number of homogeneous components of $f$.

Proceed by induction on $m$.

First suppose $m=1$.

Then $f=\ell(f)$, hence $f\in T$.

Next suppose $m\ge 2$ and assume, as the inductive hypothesis, that if $g\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]\cap K$ has $m-1$ homogeneous components, then $g\in T$.

Then since $f-\ell(f)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]\cap K$ has $m-1$ homogeneous components, it follows, by the inductive hypothesis, that $f-\ell(f)\in T$, hence $f\in T$, which completes the induction.

This completes the proof of lemma $(3)$.

Note that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ has fraction field $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, and since $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a UFD, it follows that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is integrally closed.

Now suppose $w\in K$ is integral over $T$.

Then $w\in\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ (since $K\subset\mathbb{C}(x,y)$), and $w$ is integral
over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (since $T\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y]$), hence
since $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is integrally closed, it follows that $w\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Thus we have $w\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]\cap K$, so $w\in T$ (since $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\cap K=T$).

It follows that $T$ is integrally closed, hence $T$ is the integral closure of $R$.